# SharePoint List - Export to Excel only downloads owssvr.dll not .iqy

Tags: list, excel, export

Office 2016
SharePoint 2013

For any SharePoint list, when I click on the 'Export to Excel' button on the 'List' ribbon, I am prompted to download the owssvr.dll file.  When it download it will download as owssvr.dll instead of owssvr.dll.iqy.  When I try to open owssvr.dll, I get the following error in Excel.

[image]

When the file opens, it is only the API information and not the data from the list.

How do I get a SharePoint list to download as a .iqy file instead of a .dll file?

Comment: do not know why it is downds like this, but a temporary solution is to rename the file and add **.iqy** at the end of file name. It will open perfectly in Excel